# Horizontal Scroll issue on website

Tags: html, css

On my site:

http://madlov.com/qa

I'm noticing that, if I hold the right arrow key... or click and move the mouse to the right (anywhere on the page), there is a bunch of space to the right... the pages scrolls, although I've turned off scroll bars with:

```
overflow-x: hidden
```

how can I control this behavior or at least understand which element is causing the horizontal scroll.

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this in? Looks fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: Get the Chrome Web Developer extension or Firefox Web Developer addons. Inspect element and turn on block outlining and you can debug these issues very quickly

Comment: `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` aren't supported by all browsers, though most are fine. I don't see a scrollbar in Chrome. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your should really get rid of your overflow hidden on the body... what if by browser is jsut to small to show the entire website?

the problem is `div.grid_8.prefix_3.suffix_5` (the one next to the facebook like button) it has a padding right, that pushes the max width of your site

remove the 400px padding-right and the overflow on the body. Then everyone is happy, you because you have no horizontal scroll-bars and people with small resolutions or sight problems...

You could find this out by your own by removing the elements from the DOM one by one in your favorite debugger/inspector (firebug for example)

Comment: He can get rid of the padding by removing the suffix_5 class that is adding it. It looks like he is using a CSS framework (http://960.gs) and probably does not want to modify the css itself.

Comment: @tawnman. He can still overwrite this value in the other css he has inserted.

Comment: in chrome inspect element I edited the page markup removing suffix_5 and the horizontal scroll bar disappeared. Love chrome inline editing :)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've removed .suffix_5 and the issue seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There is one over-sized div that's causing the problem. Its location is:

```
<html> 
<body> 
<div class="nav-bot-wrapper sm-shadow">
<div class="logo container_12 clearfix">
<div class="grid_8 prefix_3 suffix_5">
```

There is too much padding-right in the `.container_12 .suffix_5` class (960.css, line 327)

Answer (score 0):

You do not turn off scrollbars, you just hide overflow and so there are none of them.

In your code look for elements with fixed width; padding or other parameters that might cause this problem.